# Reusing methods in python by name

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests

I'm using python to perform some automated test activities (REST API testing) with no test framework. It's just regular python script not using OO approach.

As such, I'm running 400 tests, but let's say that I have 20 endpoints, each then getting hit 20 times with different parameters.

Now, I've created each "test" as a function, meaning I have:

```
def test1():
   pass
def test2():
   pass
...
def test20():
   pass
```

and then I call them in the main method one after another:

```
test1()
test2()
...
test20()
```

Is there a way to give method an "alias" name? I know it might sound crazy, but It's common need in QA world.

So for example, I want to have a parametric array "tests" where I could say:

```
tests = [2,4,5-7]
```

Which would then run only:

```
test2()
test4()
test5()
test6()
test7()
```

I'm currently commenting out, and uncommenting lines not needed in particular moments, but I have larger test with 100 "tests" in front of me, and commenting 60-70 lines is crazy.

What would be the best approach to avoid commenting, but execute just certain parts of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. Probably the easiest is:

```
testDict = {1:test1,
           2:test2,
           3:test2,
           ..
           }

test = [2,4,5,6,7]

for testNum in tests:
   testDict[testNum]()
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks Tommy. I forgot I can actually put functions in a dictionary. It does the job. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `inspect.getmembers(<Class name>,inspect.ismethod)` to retrieve the list of the methods from your class.

Then you make a loop to retrieve only those starting with 'test*', and finally you create a function to loop over each test* function you want to run. To do so you build the string 'test' and you run eval(): `eval('test<num>')()`.

Later, if you are interested, I can send you a working code.

Sam

Comment: I don't have a Class name. It is not OO approach.

Comment: So its easier, then : use dir(<module_name>) to retrieves all methods from your module.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare a list of function names and then retrieve the corresponding objects and call them.

Proof of concept:

```
import sys 

def test1():
    print("T1")
def test2():
    print("T2")
def test3():
    print("T3")
def test5():
    print("T5")

run_tests = [1,3,2,4]

this_module = sys.modules[__name__]
for test in run_tests:
    func_name = "test{}".format(test)
    try:
        func = getattr(this_module, func_name)
    except AttributeError:
        # no such function
        continue
    try:
        func()
    except TypeError:
        # not a function
        pass
```